# Use Single Server to run SQL Server Agent Jobs for all environments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

We have a dedicated server to run SQL Server Agent jobs for each environment (ie., DEV, QA, STG,...). We almost have 20 environments.

Looks like the table below.

[image]

So currently we have 20 servers for running jobs in each environment. Now we are in the process of optimization ie., by reducing server usage.

As a part of this operation, we planned to have only one server to run jobs for all environments.

List of points below to be considered to check the feasibility.

1. We have around 100 jobs each have its own config files based on each environment.
2. Each job is running on its own schedule and the timing differs based on each environment.
3. Each job has some packages which may connect different servers so we may get some connectivity issues.

Approach-1: Replicate same set of jobs for each environment in one single server. (For example, if we have 100 jobs in one environment, then we must create 100*20 jobs since we have 20 environments). We know it is a complex manual process however it is a one time activity. We are not sure about the connectivity between servers across all environments are feasible or not.

[image]

Approach-2: Have one set of jobs (100 jobs). Configure the single job to multiple environments and create different schedules based on each environment.

[image]

We already started to work on the first Approach-1. We are not sure about the Second Approach and its feasibility but we like to do Approach-2.

Please suggest a best approach other than this or between these two with Pros and Cons.

Comment: Check out this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-execute-jobs-on-multiple-sql-servers/

Comment: @CriticalError: Thanks for sharing the article, but here also we need master and target server. In our case, we are trying to merge multiple servers jobs to one server.